# How to use set-string in css to get my text in header only?

Tags: html, css, typography

I would like to set string in my header, but I don't want it to be visible in my content.
I have this in my html:

```
<h2>Text I want in my header</h2>
```

If used with css I have, I get text in my header as well as in my content.

```
@page {
  @top-left {
    content: counter(page);
    height: 1cm;
    width: 1cm; }
  @top-right {
    content: string(heading);
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%; } }

 html body h2 {
    break-before: always;
    string-set: heading content(); }
```

Can I fix somehow CSS or I need another approach to get what I want?

Comment: can't you give your header an id?

Comment: as far as i have seen css is visible...............PHP may be the solution